# Run SSRS Report Builder

Tags: mssql

I was wondering if anyone out there has had success running SSRS's report builder in GNU/Linux?

I have recently upgraded to ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS yet I still need to support SSRS Reports. I have been using report builder to create these things in wondows in the past.

Answer (score 0):

SSRS does not operate properly in Ubuntu even with WINE.  The only way to build SSRS reports is to use SSRS reporting software from within Windows, so you would need to deploy a Windows VM to install SSRS Reports generator tools onto and then generate reports with.

There's no way to natively run this within Linux or Ubuntu at the moment, and SSRS toolkits don't run correctly from within Wine.